# Progress of the raptor engine

Tags: spacex, testing, raptor

I have seen that SpaceX has tested a scaled down version of the raptor, but that was about a year ago. Does anyone know the current progress? Do they have a full scale model? Have they hot fired a full scale raptor? If not, is there a target date for any of it?

Answer (score 2):

They have operational engines used for testing the starship prototype. On April 5 2019 they did an tethered hop just barly lifting of.

https://www.google.se/amp/s/www.space.com/amp/spacex-starhopper-test-hop-end-of-tether.html

Comment: In the last week they have flown untethered to 20m

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia is your friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raptor_(rocket_engine_family)#Engine_development_and_testing): yes, the Raptor has been test-fired several times. However, as SpaceX aim for max reusability, they test differently than with a disposable engine, beginning with brief bursts.